# Nvidia after upgrade 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, 14.04

I have some weird behaviour from nvidia drivers so far. My systemparts that are involved:

```
nvidia GTX 560
Two Screens
Ubuntu 14.04, fresh update from 12.04,
```

When I execute `sudo nvidia-settings` and click on apply none of the adjustments are taking place. On closing nvidia-settings I get an error in the terminal:

```
   (nvidia-settings:24231): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 5984 was not found when attempting to remove it
The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 1154 error_code 2 request_code 157 minor_code 25)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I am not getting any ideas from the logs either:

```
dmesg | grep nvidia
[   22.493961] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   22.498143] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[  664.524208] init: nvidia-persistenced main process (23947) terminated with status 1
```

Something reappears allways in xorg.log:

```
[    33.178] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    33.178] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
```

Well... I hope anyone can help me! Thank you in advance!

Edit:
What I tried so far:

- Purging nvidia-drivers and reinstalling them
- deleting xorg.conf
- executing `nvidia-xconfig`

Edit 2:
Just had an idea: Launching a game from my steam account. Doing that I get:

```
Could not find required OpenGL enty point 'glColorMaskIndexedEXT'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
```

Comment: Can you give the output of "nvidia-settings --version"